# How to insert C# variables in Azure Blob Index Queries

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

Foolowing MS Docs here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-index-how-to?tabs=net

Some examples are given for queries:

```
// Blob index queries and selection
String singleEqualityQuery = @"""Archive"" = 'false'";
String andQuery = @"""Archive"" = 'false' AND ""Priority"" = '01'";
String rangeQuery = @"""Date"" >= '2020-04-20' AND ""Date"" <= '2020-04-30'";
String containerScopedQuery = @"@container = 'mycontainer' AND ""Archive"" = 'false'";
```

These examples are useless as no one in the real world is going to hard code queries using static values.

If i try to insert a variable into a query when using the 'AND' staement then the string won't compile. Example:

```
var varibale1 = "test1";
var varibale2 = "test2";
// Not working!
query = @"""folderDepth"" = '" + varibale1 + "' AND ""parentFolder"" = 'hardCodedvalue'";
// Hard coded values
query = @"""folderDepth"" = 'test1' AND ""parentFolder"" = 'test2'";
```

[image]

Comment: try to compose the query with use $"" and \" (escape) to put " in your string
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot below shows the MS code example I was trying to work with:

[image]

Each index tag in the above example queries are wrapped in two sets of double quotes. This would work until I started inserting variables into the query as shown below:

[image]

The query that worked for me was to escape the second index tag in the string i.e. ParentFolder.

```
// -----------------------------
// ----- Tested and worked -----
// -----------------------------
string query4 = @"""FolderDepth"" = '" + varibale1 + "' AND \"ParentFolder\" = '" + varibale2 + "'";
```